# Unable to remove Freeform fields from entries in control panel

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a client that's using Freeform 3.0.6 with EE 2.5.2 with multiple forms on their site.  The issue they're having is that when they login to thru the EE control panel to view the form submissions, certain fields are blank, and actually shouldn't even be in the current view.

What I'm wondering is, how do I remove these superfluous fields from the view? Please see the attachments to illustrate what I'm talking about.

Thank you!!
[image: client clicks edit to view form submitted data]

[image: would like to remove these superfluous fields]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Freeform v3 you aren't able to hide unused fields from the view.

You can do this in [**Freeform v4**](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/) though which has a completely different work flow for forms and data.

The upgrade from v3.x to v4.x can be involved. Here are [**instructions from Solspace**](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/upgrade_3.x-4.x/) to help with an upgrade if you go that route.

> **NOTE:** Backup files & DB before upgrading... This is a big upgrade.